# in gtk# how does one obtain the StyleContext of a MenuBar Widget?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk3, gtk#

There is a C++ example ([How to use CssStyleProvider in Gtkmm3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666387/how-to-use-cssstyleprovider-in-gtkmm3)  ) that shows:
widget.get_style_context()
However there is no such method available for Widgets in gtk#. I'm just not connecting the dots between a CssProvider and the target widget to which it should be applied. Getting tripped up by the inability to obtain the StyleContext.What I'm ultimately after is the ability to make a MenuBar transparent via a CssProvider using this technique (first in answers): [How do I really make a GTK+ 3 GtkLayout transparent/draw theme background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940588/how-do-i-really-make-a-gtk-3-gtklayout-transparent-draw-theme-background)

Comment: The default Mono install with GTK# is for 2.x not 3.x, you can access 3.x via nuget or source : https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp

Comment: Yes I know - I'm using Gtk3.

Comment: Child opacity cannot override the parent container's opacity. So much for that try. Sigh. :-)